# How to display highchart y axis with constistant data

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, charts, highcharts

I have a highchart column graph, in that at some time the y axis data are displaying as [1000,2000,3000,4000] and some times as [1k, 2k, 3k, 4k].

How can I fix it to single type of data.

Regards,
Navin Leon

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Compare http://jsfiddle.net/BNFe5/

The difference is here:

```
yAxis: {
    labels: {
        formatter: function() {
            return this.value;
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: What if I want to display the K values instead of numbers eg: instead of [1000,2000] how can display [1k,2k] ? is tat possible?

Comment: @NavinLeon use `return Math.round(this.value/1000) + 'k';` in `formatter` function.

Comment: thanks @Cheery I found Highcharts.numberFormat( this.value/1000, 0) + "K"

Answer (score 5):

For Converting your yaxis values into 1k,2k,3k,4k,etc:

```
yAxis: 
{
    labels: 
    { 
      formatter: function() 
      {
         return Math.round(this.value/1000) + 'k';
      }
    }
},
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using thousands and millions in one chart, check this out.

```
yAxis: {
    labels: {
        formatter: function () {
            if (this.value.toFixed(0) >= 1000000) {
                return '$' + this.value.toFixed(0) / 1000000 + 'M';
            } else {
                return '$' + this.value.toFixed(0) / 1000 + 'K';
            }
        }
    },
    title: {
        text: ''
    }
},
```